# get index of li in ul

Tags: jquery, html, indexing, html-lists

I have the following ul

```
<ul id="menu">
<li class="item"><a href=""></li>
<li class="item"><a href=""></li>
<li class="item"><a href=""></li>
</ul>
```

when I click on an anchor I want to retrieve the index of the parent li

jquery:

```
$("#menu li.item a").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var current_menuitem = $(this).closest("li.item");
      var menu_items = $(current_menuitem).closest("ul#menu");
      var menu_index = (menu_items.index(current_menuitem)) + 1;

      console.log("id: " + menu_index);
    });
  });
```

Comment: index is now 0 at each click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use:

```
$("#menu li.item a").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e){
            console.log($(this).parent().index());
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EzYeH/89/)**

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$("#menu ul").find('a').click(function () {
    var str = $(this).parents("li").index();
    alert(str);
});
```